# confusion overloading memberfunctions on rvalues and lvalues

Tags: c++, lvalue, rvalue, overload-resolution

I have the following setup:

```
struct foo
{
    void bar( ) &  { std::cout << "lvalue\n"; }
    void bar( ) && { std::cout << "rvalue\n"; }

    ~foo( ) { bar( ); }
};


int main( int arg, char **argv )
{
    foo{ }.bar();
}
```

which leads to the output of

```
rvalue
lvalue
```

I do not understand the output of the dtor which is always `lvalue` 
no matter how hard I try. While I agree that taking the address
similar to

```
(*this).bar( ); // sure enough this will print lvalue
```

calls the lvalue-overload I do not understand why I can never get an output of `rvalue`for the dtor.

I find this strange since the object is an rvalue first and somehow binds to an lvalue before being destructed. What's the matter here?

Comment: You miss tracking the constructors.

Comment: ... `foo( ) { bar( ); }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this` is a prvalue, but `*this` is a lvalue, naturally it will call lvalue ref-qualifiers:

```
§ 5.3.1 Unary operators [expr.unary.op]
```

> The unary * operator performs *indirection*: the expression to which it is applied shall be a pointer to an
>   object type, or a pointer to a function type and the result is an **lvalue** referring to the object or function
>   to which the expression points.

From cppreference, [this pointer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/this):

> When a non-static class member is used in any of the contexts where the this keyword is allowed (non-static member function bodies, member initializer lists, default member initializers), **the implicit this-> is automatically added before the name**, resulting in a member access expression (which, if the member is a virtual member function, results in a virtual function call).

*Note*: calling this-> is equivalent to calling (*this).

```
#include <iostream>

struct foo
{
    void bar( ) &  { std::cout << "lvalue\n"; x(); }
    void bar( ) && { std::cout << "rvalue\n"; x(); }

    void x( ) & { std::cout << "x lvalue\n"; }
    void x( ) && { std::cout << "x rvalue\n"; }

    ~foo( ) { bar( ); }
};


int main( int arg, char **argv )
{
    foo{ }.bar();
}
```

Prints:

```
rvalue
x lvalue
lvalue
x lvalue
```

If, for some reason, you really want to call a rvalue function, you could cast the this pointer to a rvalue reference:

```
~foo( ) { static_cast<foo&&>(*this).bar( ); }
```

Or using `std::move`:

```
~foo( ) { std::move(*this).bar( ); }
```

Comment: thanks for elaborating. does this mean that within a context where `this` is allowed (which is basically in all member-functions including ctor and dtor) the object will be treated as an lvalue while the outside value-category can be different? (voted up but do not have enough rep yet).

Comment: @david Yes. Simply using this, explicitly or implicitly will call lvalue ref-qualifiers. Added a *solution* to call rvalue ref-qualifiers.

Comment: no - I do not want to force calling the rvalue-overload. I was simply confused that the object appeared to be an rvalue and client-code would yield this output. dtor however said lvalue which seemed strange to me since the same object was a rvalue and lvalue depending on wheter a member-function was being called

Comment: thank you for clarifying! any way of forwarding the 'outside' value-category? (just interested, no usecase yet, would propably use a non-member function there).