# Is `reinterpret_cast` actually good for anything?

Tags: c++, casting, c++17, reinterpret-cast, type-punning

I [recently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68568940/generating-a-warning-when-a-member-function-is-invoked-on-a-temporary-object) [learned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68569078/how-to-reinterpret-or-cast-an-object-with-known-memory-layout-without-getting-un) that it is Undefined Behavior to reinterpret a POD as a different POD by `reinterpret_cast`ing its address. So I'm just wondering what a potential use-case of `reinterpret_cast` might be, if it can't be used for what its name suggests?

Comment: It has some uses probably the most common is in implementing the PImpl idiom using a `void *`

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/573294/when-to-use-reinterpret-cast

Comment: Casting a POD or an array of scalars to a char array, for instance.

Comment: @RichardCritten - You don't need `reinterpret_cast` to convert object pointers from `void*`

Comment: @bipll I was getting failures when casting between two PODs that both contain only `std::array<double,2>`.

Comment: You can reinterpret_cast to a character type (ref or pointer

Comment: @m88 No, you mustn’t use `reinterpret_cast` for that. Use `static_cast`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yeah my bad, I thought `static_cast` was for upcast only.

Comment: Not to say that it has to be designed that way, but good luck doing just about anything in the Windows API without `reinterpret_cast`s. For example, window messages often have a pointer passed in as an integral type and you're expected to cast it back.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number Regarding the request in the comments of the deleted answer, here is the defect report : http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/p1839r2.pdf

Comment: There is a list of use cases for `reinterpret_cast` [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast#Explanation). Note that most of those use cases are not actually useful. For example, converting an object to its own type or simply allowing a back-and-forth between two types with the intermediate value being otherwise unusable (ex. can convert `A` to `B` but using `B` is UB, though it can be converted back to `A`).

Comment: I don't think this question would have been closed if the title was more objective (ex. "What is a well defined use case for reinterpret_cast?". Maybe retitling it will see it reopened.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Maybe another title would be better. But even the current title is entirely fine. The question is fine as it is, there’s need not be anything opinion-based about it.

Comment: [Is reinterpret_cast mostly useless?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5057614/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two situations in which I’ve used `reinterpret_cast`:

1. To cast to and from `char*` for the purpose of serialisation or when talking to a legacy API. In this case the cast from `char*` to an object pointer is still strictly speaking UB (even though done very frequently). And you don’t actually *need* `reinterpret_cast` here — you could use `memcpy` instead, but the cast *might* under specific circumstances avoid a copy (but in situations where reinterpreting the bytes is valid in the first place, `memcpy` usually doesn’t generate any redundant copies either, the compiler is smart enough for that).
2. To cast pointers from/to `std::uintptr_t` to serialise them across a legacy API or to perform some non-pointer arithmetic on them. This is definitely an odd beast and doesn’t happen frequently (even in low-level code) but consider the situation where one wants to exploit the fact that pointers on a given platform don’t use the most significant bits, and these bits can thus be used to store some bit flags. Garbage collector implementations occasionally do this. The lower bits of a pointer can sometimes also be used, if the programmer knows that the pointer will always be aligned e.g. at an 8 byte boundary (so the lowest three bits must be 0).

But to be honest I can’t remember the last concrete, legitimate situation where I’ve actually used `reinterpret_cast`. It’s definitely many years ago.

Comment: I've always thought of `reinterpret_cast` as a way to say to a following developer "This is probably undefined behavior but we have to do it because it's how this API works, here be dragons" in a nice searchable package. If it was safe you'd be using `static_cast`

Comment: @Mgetz That’s a common misunderstanding. `reinterpret_cast`’s  purpose, at least nowadays, is definitely not to exploit UB. You really shouldn’t *ever* rely on UB (ignoring some standards defects). You can rely on *implementation-defined* behaviour, but that‘s fundamentally different. `reinterpret_cast` helps exploit implementation-defined behaviour, not UB. But you’re right that *historically* UB used to be treated in a more blasé fashion, and some platform APIs outright required UB.

Comment: I guess what I'm saying is that `reinterpret_cast` is basically a good way to indicate something has dragons associated even if they aren't technically UB. Things like casting a pointer through `void*` for example. Yes you can do it with `static_cast` but it's a better indication to the following developer to use `reinterpret_cast` to indicate the danger.

Comment: @Mgetz No, why would it be better? On the contrary, using `static_cast` in this situation is definitely better, because it indicates that the result of the cast is well-defined, safe and does exactly what’s expected. `reinterpret_cast`, if anything, give the impression “I don’t know exactly what I’m doing”. Always prefer the narrowest available cast, only drop to more permissible casts if you have to.

Comment: Just to emphasise this point: you should *definitely not* use `reinterpret_cast` where `static_cast` works. Even ignoring other reasons, this is error-prone! Because the compiler will save you from yourself if you’re using `static_cast` but are accidentally trying to cast the wrong type. With `reinterpret_cast` the compiler gives up and won’t catch many silly mistakes that using `static_cast` will prevent.

Comment: In the specific case of casting to and from `void*` I'll extremely disagree. It's not safe despite being defined. Using `reinterpret_cast` makes it quickly searchable in a codebase, `static_cast` does not. For the simple reason you mention above, that you should be using it. So unless you make your own inline fake cast `mine::dangerous_cast` I'd use `reinterpret_cast` so it's easy to find.

Comment: @Mgetz See my last comment. Even if casting away type safety is inherently unsafe, using `reinterpret_cast` makes the code *less safe*. `reinterpret_cast` may be a warning sign in your personal coding style, but it’s also the *cause* of errors. At any rate, `void*` itself is sufficient warning. Relying on `reinterpret_cast` as a warning sign is completely redundant.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux read up... I mentioned doing that 

Comment: Maybe you haven’t used it this way, but the [first-member case](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30617519/8586227) is worth mentioning as well.

Answer (score 1):

Conforming implementations of C and C++ are allowed to extend the semantics of C or C++ by behaving meaningfully even in cases where the Standards would not require them to do so.  Implementations that do so will may be more suitable for a wider range of tasks than implementations that do not.  In many cases, it is useful to have consistent *syntax* to specify constructs which will be processed meaningfully and consistently by implementations that are designed to be suitable for low-level programming tasks, even if implementations which are not designed to be suitable for such purposes would process them nonsensically.

Answer (score 0):

One very frequent use case is when you're working with C library functions that take an opaque `void *` that gets forwarded to a callback function. Using `reinterpret_cast` on both sides of the fence, so to speak, keeps everything proper.

Comment: You don’t need `reinterpret_cast` to cast object pointers to/from `void*` (you need it for *objects*, but that’s UB, though still done).

Comment: `static_cast` works (and I would have said is preferable?)

Comment: @M.M I'd actually say `reinterpret_cast` is preferable although you can do it with `static_cast`. The reasoning being that use of `reinterpret_cast` should always indicate danger. Casting through `void*` is always a point of danger IMO.

Comment: The implicit conversion to a `void*` is a `static_cast`, and to un-do an implicit conversion you also use `static_cast`.  It is the proper one to use for this.